# load image progress bar on parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

i want to load image with progress bar on parse sdk with android,
because sometimes when i scroll down on the recycle view ,some images wont show.
in my callback method of the array list that return from the server i get all the list objects (i see the title of each photo) but not the photo itself

this is my code under onBindViewHolder method of RecycleView

//getting big photo

```
    ParseFile photoFile = photo.getParseFile("photo");
    if (photoFile != null) {
        viewHolder.userImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
        viewHolder.userImage.
        loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {


            }
        });
    }
```

this is a screen shot from my feeds app ....

[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/257efrn.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

Add some progress bar to your layout for example below ParseImageView and it will be shown during the loading of Image and automatically will be covered with image when loading complete, or you can change visibility of your progress bar and hide it in the GetDataCallback

Comment: Yep, there is no way of getting progress value in case of using Parse's getDataInBackground() method. So the only way is to set your Progress Bar to indeterminate progress.